# tsql comma delimited testing for value

Tags: t-sql

I've been given a table with a few fields that hold comma-separated values (either blank or Y/N) like so (and the field name where this data is stored is People_Notified):

```
Y,,N,
,Y,,N
,,N,Y
```

Each 'slot' relates to a particular field value and I need to now include that particular field name in the string as well (in this case Parent, Admin, Police and Medical) but inserting a "N" if the current value is blank but leaving the existing Y's and N's in place.  So for the above example, where there are four known slots, I would want a tsql statement to end up with:

```
Parent=Y,Admin=N,Police=N,Medical=N
Parent=N,Admin=Y,Police=N,Medical=N
Parent=N,Admin=N,Police=N,Medical=Y
```

I tried to use a combination of CHARINDEX and CASE but haven't figured a way to make this work.

js

Comment: why don't you want to use 4 separate fields?

Comment: He says he's been "given" the table.  I assume he has no control over the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a bit messy, in theory can be done in one statement:

```
select 
'Parent=' +stuff((stuff((stuff(
substring((replace(
(','+(replace((replace(@People_Notified,',,,',',N,N,')),',,',',N,'))+','),',,',',N,')),2,7),7,0,
'Medical=')),5,0,'Police=')),3,0,'Admin=')
```

broken down is easier to follow:

```
declare @People_Notified varchar(100)=',,Y,Y' -- test variable
-- Insert Ns
set @People_Notified= (select replace(@People_Notified,',,,',',N,N,')) -- case two consecutive missing 
set @People_Notified= (select replace(@People_Notified,',,',',N,')) -- case one missing 
set @People_Notified= (select replace((','+@People_Notified+','),',,',',N,')) -- case start or end missing 
set @People_Notified= substring(@People_Notified,2,7) -- remove extra commas added previously
-- Stuff the labels
select 'Parent=' +stuff((stuff((stuff(@People_Notified,7,0,'Medical=')),5,0,'Police=')),3,0,'Admin=')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use XQuery in SQL Server, I don't think you need to get too complex.  You could do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, REPLACE('<pn>' + REPLACE(People_Notified, ',', '</pn><pn>') + '</pn>', '<pn></pn>', '<pn>N</pn>')).query('
    concat("Parent=", data(/pn[1])[1], ",Admin=", data(/pn[2])[1], ",Police=", data(/pn[3])[1], ",Medical=", data(/pn[4])[1])
')
FROM ...
```

Explanation:  Construct an XML-like string out of the original delimited string by replacing commas with closing and opening tags.  Add an opening tag to the start and a closing tag to the end.  Replace each empty element with one containing "N".  Convert the XML-like string into actual XML data so that you can use XQuery.  Then just concatenate what you need using [concat()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the right indexes for the elements' data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
;WITH cteXML (Id, Notified)
AS
(
    SELECT Id,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Notified><YN>' 
        + REPLACE([notified],',', '</YN><YN>') 
        + '</YN></Notified>') AS Notified
    FROM People_Notified
)

select id, 
'Parent=' + case Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[1]','varchar(1)') when '' then 'N' else Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[1]','varchar(1)') end + ',' +
'Admin=' + case Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[2]','varchar(1)') when '' then 'N' else Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[2]','varchar(1)') end + ',' +
'Police=' + case Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[3]','varchar(1)') when '' then 'N' else Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[3]','varchar(1)') end + ',' +
'Medical=' + case Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[4]','varchar(1)') when '' then 'N' else Notified.value('/Notified[1]/YN[4]','varchar(1)') end Notified
from cteXML
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08ab06/1/0)

Check [this page](http://jahaines.blogspot.in/2009/06/converting-delimited-string-of-values.html) out for an explanation of what the XML stuff is doing.

[This page](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) has a pretty thorough look at the various ways you can split a delimited string into rows.